# how to hidden name folder and only show vim type "*.vim"

Tags: shell, unix, command, zsh

**how to filter it?**

how is called name for filter or hidden?

```
$ ls /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/*.vim | cut -f 4
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/blue.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/darkblue.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/default.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/delek.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/desert.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/elflord.vim
....
```

I want like

```
blue.vim
darkblue.vim
default.vim
delek.vim
desert.vim
elflord.vim
evening.vim
koehler.vim
morning.vim
...
```

how to solve?

Comment: (1) Why do you do the `cut`?  (2) `cd /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors; ls *.vim; cd -` would just list the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/*.vim`

itself would list only the file names.

If at all your output is still the same. use the AWK command to fetch the last field after using "/" as the field separator.

```
ls /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/*.vim | cut -f 4 | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

Good Luck.